# blackberry socket connection

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to write simple socket program in blackberry, but it is not working.  I have tried a lot.  Please someone help me.  Is any additional settings are required with simulator?

Thanks in advance :)

```
try
{
    StreamConnection conn =(StreamConnection)Connector.open("socket://some ip:4444;deviceside=false,Connector.READ_WRITE,true");
    OutputStreamWriter _out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.openOutputStream());
    String data = "This is a test\n";
    int length = data.length();
    _out.write(data, 0, length);
    InputStreamReader _in = new InputStreamReader(conn.openInputStream());
    char[] input = new char[length];

    for ( int i = 0; i < length; ++i ) 
    {
        input[i] = (char)_in.read();
    };

    _in.close();
    _out.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

Comment: i m getting no error.build is successful.but message doesn't get sent to the server.

Comment: Successful build doesn't mean that your code will work :p. Put some try - catch block to your code and check whether there is any exception. And I'm not sure why you add "Connector.READ_WRITE,true" to the url. I think if you want to enable your connection for Read/Write then something like "Connection.setRequestProperty(key, value)" may helps you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to connect exactly how you have mentioned above then you indeed are not supposed to be able to connect:

```
StreamConnection conn =(StreamConnection)Connector.open("socket://some
ip:4444;deviceside=false,Connector.READ_WRITE,true")
```

because there was a wrongly placed quotation mark after the boolean value **`true`**, which should have been placed after ...**`deviceside=false`**, i.e. the correct `StreamConnection` should have formed somewhat like this:

```
StreamConnection conn =(StreamConnection)Connector.open("socket://some
ip:4444;deviceside=false",Connector.READ_WRITE,true);
```

The **`Connector.READ_WRITE`** and the **`boolean`** values are the parameters for the **`Connector.Open()`** method.

Answer (score -1):

check the following link it may be help you

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Different-ways-to-make-an-HTTP-or-socket-connection/ta-p/445879

Comment: answers on stackoverflow should be self contained.  Merely linking to a support forum article isn't so useful, as the forum may change their link scheme, or go away entirely.  highlighting the important part of the article, with a quotation, would be a good answer for stackoverflow.